# How do you parse a c-string?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, queue, cstring

Hi I'm trying to take a c-string from a user, input it into a queue, parse the data with a single space depending on its contents, and output the kind of data it is (int, float, word NOT string).

E.g. Bobby Joe is 12 in 3.5 months \n

Word: Bobby

Word: Joe

Word: is

Integer: 12

Word: in

Float: 3.5

Word: months

Here's my code so far:

```
int main()
{
    const int maxSize = 100;

    char cstring[maxSize];

    std::cout << "\nPlease enter a string: ";
    std::cin.getline(cstring, maxSize, '\n');

//Keyboard Buffer Function
buffer::keyboard_parser(cstring);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Function:

```
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

namespace buffer
{
    std::string keyboard_parser(char* input)
{
    //Declare Queue
    std::queue<std::string> myQueue;

    //Declare String
    std::string str;

    //Declare iStringStream
    std::istringstream isstr(input);

    //While Loop to Read iStringStream to Queue
    while(isstr >> str)
    {
        //Push onto Queue
        myQueue.push(str);

        std::string foundDataType = " ";

        //Determine if Int, Float, or Word
        for(int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++)
        {
            if(str[index] >= '0' && str[index] <= '9')
            {
                foundDataType = "Integer";
            }
            else if(str[index] >= '0' && str[index] <= '9' || str[index] == '.')
            {
                foundDataType = "Float";
                                    break;
            }
            else if(!(str[index] >= '0' && str[index] <= '9'))
            {
                foundDataType = "Word";
            }
        }

        std::cout << "\n" << foundDataType << ": " << myQueue.front();
        std::cout << "\n";

        //Pop Off of Queue
        myQueue.pop();
        }
}   
}
```

Right now with this code, it doesn't hit the cout statement, it dumps the core.

I've read about using the find member function and the substr member function, but I'm unsure of how exactly I need to implement it.

**Note:** This is homework.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** Okay everything seems to work! Fixed the float and integer issue with a break statement. Thanks to everyone for all the help!

Comment: Why a C-string? And why do you keep deliberately going off the end of your array by one? Finally, why not use a debugger?

Comment: I don't know, that's the requirement.

Comment: What requirement? From whom? Why?

Comment: Sorry, should have labeled as homework!

Comment: it should be rather `std::cin.getline(cstring, maxSize, '\n');` unless you are asking for trouble...

Comment: @m.wasowski Still getting seg fault.

Comment: Your code runs when I try it, except that I had to make maxSize const (no C++11 here). I noticed that your prompt/input pair should probably go into the loop (right now the string never changes). It is also weird that you loop maxSize times  as if you wanted to iterate char by char through the string, not through different strings.

Comment: Yeah I keep getting a segmentation fault, no idea what's going on. Using gcc.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Well, the thing is, the user should be able to input a string and the program parses it for them... So it shouldn't be running the prompt multiple times.

Comment: I see. What's your input?

Comment: Right now I'm just inputting "please work" but it isn't outputting anything at all... Just a seg fault.

Comment: Well, `std::string parseIt(input) {` isn't even valid syntax...

Comment: Yeah I changed it within my code to be 'char &input' but nothing...

Comment: Uhh, `char&` is not the right type for that function.  It should be `char*`.

Comment: Whoa! Okay it works! Thanks! But how do I make it so that it parses the words from the space delimiter? Cause right now it just printed my input 100 times...

Comment: That's because you loop 100 times pushing stuff onto the queue and outputting.  You probably want to use something like `string::find`, or use `istringstream`

Comment: Alright, thanks I'll try that out right now.

Comment: Actually, is it possible to push it onto the queue character by character until it hits a white space and then analyze the contents of the queue from that point?

Comment: Yes, but it's a wasteful and kinda pointless approach.  You would push all characters onto the queue (until you hit the string terminator), then pop elements off the queue until you hit whitespace.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what the instructor wants us to do for queue practice. How would you implement it? Obviously you'd use the find member function but how exactly?

Comment: Actually, no I would use a string stream, and put whole words in the queue:  `for( string s, istringstream iss(input); iss >> s; myQueue.push(s) );`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Going to update and finish code in a little while. Thanks to everyone for their input!

Comment: Right it all works but now I'm stuck on determining the datatypes...

Comment: Couple notes on your current code... your `for` loop goes over the string setting the data type according to the characters it sees: say is saw `"1.3A2"` -> when `index` is `0` it sees `'1'` so sets `foundDataType` to `"Integer"`, then `index` `1` sees `'.'` and overwrites `"Float"`, then "3" sets "Integer" again, "A" so "Word", '2' so "Integer" - you can't decide using only the final character.  Separately, you should support a leading '-' (and probably '+'), and floats in C++ can be written like 1E2 for 1 times 10 to the power of 2, i.e. 100 - you may or may not care to support that.

Comment: Thanks, so how would you recommend fixing the if statement?

Comment: Ah-ha! Figured it out, just used a break statement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::istream`s are very useful for parsing text in C++... often with an initial read of a line from a string, then further parsing from a `std::istringstream` constructed with the line content.

```
const char* token_type(const std::string& token)
{
    // if I was really doing this, I'd use templates to avoid near-identical code
    // but this is an easier-to-understand starting point...
    {
        std::istringstream iss(token);
        int i;
        char c;
        if (iss >> i && !(iss >> c)) return "Integer";
    }
    {
        std::istringstream iss(token);
        float f;
        char c; // used to check there's no trailing characters that aren't part
                // of the float value... e.g. "1Q" is not a float (rather, "word").
        if (iss >> f && !(iss >> c)) return "Float";
    }
    return "Word";
}

const int maxSize = 100;  // Standard C++ won't let you create an array unless const
char cstring[maxSize];
std::cout << "\nPlease enter a string: ";
if (std::cin.getline(cstring, maxSize, '\n'))
{
    std::istringstream iss(cstring);
    std::string token;
    while (iss >> token) // by default, streaming into std::string takes a space-...
        token_queue.push(token);    // ...separated word at a time

    for (token_queue::const_iterator i = token_queue.begin();
         i != token_queue.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << token_type(*i) << ": " << *i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @PeterSchneider Oh jeez... half asleep still... fixed.  Re `getline` et al - the assignment apparently asks for "C" strings and `queue`s, and I think the OP's interpretation of what's expected there's sane, so have retained that.  Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm going to see if it does exactly what I need it to do and modify as needed.

Comment: I also took the liberty to fix the wrong string length in getline (or did you try to make a case for strings ? ;-) )

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I cut-and-pasted without reading...! :-/  Thanks!

Comment: @user3062299 `iss >> i` consumes any leading whitespace in the input stream's buffer (there won't be any because `iss >> token` had already ensured tokens had no whitespace), then reads characters until it's either managed to extract an integral value or failed (e.g. successes "1X" -> 1, "0.2" -> "0", "-3" -> -3, "+4" -> 4; failures "X1", "--2", "E10", "-+2").  The state of the `istringstream` afterwards reflects whether the parsing succeeded, and in a boolean context the object will evaluate `true` or `false` accordingly, which is why use in `if` is convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Your queue is sensible: it contains `std::string`s. Unfortunately, each of those is initialised by you passing `cstring` in without any length information and, since you certainly aren't null-terminating the C-strings (in fact, you're going one-off-the-end of each one), that's seriously asking for trouble.

Read directly into a `std::string`.

Comment: While this is all true and I heartily agree with your advice, I wonder: afaik getline() terminates the char array after the terminator has been encountered by writing a 0 char. With the apparently manual input it's likely that the input is shorter than 99 chars so that the index issue of "n+1" instead of "n-1" shouldn't be a problem. So with input consisting of short lines, cstring should be 0 terminated.

Comment: Now I'm getting a segmentation fault with the queue. I'm totally new to queues so I'm not sure how to properly use them.

Comment: What book or other resource do you use?

Comment: Right now, I'm using Data Structures and Other Objects Using C++ by Michael Main and Walter Savitch, fourth edition.